# Sometimes Cassette doesn't rewrite a background-image rule

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, image, cassette

Context:
http://getcassette.net/documentation/stylesheets

Specifically:

> Image URLs in the CSS are rewritten. For example, a file
>   ~/styles/main.css, with the content:
>
> ```
> body { background-image: url(img/bg.jpg); }
> ```
>
> is transformed into:
>
> ```
> body { background-image: url(/_assets/images/styles/img/bg_25cb72e61bd5ag2_jpg);
> ```

---

Now in my particular case for example, in my .less file, I might have a rule like this:

```
.ribbon {
    background: url("/Public/image/blue-rib.png") no-repeat;
}
```

And Cassette is supposed to rewrite it and the browser actually receives this rule:

```
.ribbon {    
    background: url("/_cassette/file/Public/images/blue-rib_81ab1e7f2fdb27c91a9e9b41eed420390e21f7e0.png") no-repeat;
}
```

And the image displays fine.

In this particular case, using the same idea, the background rule **is not** rewritten by cassette and the users receives the regular rule I manually entered in the .less file.

Here are the facts:

- The working and non-working rules are both in the same .less file.
- The image is correctly in my Visual Studio project, in a folder `/Public/images`.
- Using the Google Chrome web tool, I can see the rule is `background: url("/Public/image/blue-rib.png") no-repeat;` - Not rewritten as it should be by Cassette.

Any ideas on what might the cause of this?

I tried changing to debug=false in web.config, running the app and nothing works.

Tried switching back to debug=true and still no dice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Exactly why is this tagged `C#` and `ASP.NET MVC 3` ?

Comment: I agree with removing the C# tag, but not the MVC3 tag.

Comment: Do you see any errors or notifications in the /_cassette diagnostics' startup trace?

Answer (score 1):

Do the images exist on disk? Cassette skips images it can't find.

Also, does switching to CSS relative URLs work?

Comment: Yes, the image does exist on disc. Can you explain what this means, `does switching to CSS relative URLs work?`? Thanks for your help!